# Brachychiton Populneus Trunk Cracking

Tags: trees

I have a Brachychiton Populneus and it is green as ever but the trunk is cracking and sapping.[image]  Could you let me know what may be wrong?

Comment: Did this just happen this year?

Comment: Welcome to SE Gardening! Can you specify the location(Country, state etc.,) of this tree.

Comment: Can you show the whole tree, because some trees outgrow the pace of their bark, and others have 2 trees rubbing against each other so the bark loosens?